# How to make multiple bootstrap divs to scroll horizontally?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I tried using overflow-x to make it horizontally scrollable. still extra divs are coming down. Is there any way to make it scrollable after using full screen width. please any help. Thank you.

```css
.card{
  display:block;
  background-color:green;
  border:2px solid black;
  overflow-x:auto;
  whitespace:nowrap;
}  
.card-body{
  display:block;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share an online/live example of what you want to achieve? Also I would suggest that you add relevant CSS and Javascript/else snippets for us to help you.

Comment: From the moment you are setting the flex grid of bootstrap, it will wrap. Just replace `row` by `d-flex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `row` class by `d-flex` and from medium screen it will scroll horizontal as you wish.

It is because `row` in bootstrap 4 include `flex-wrap:wrap;`.

### DEMO

```css
.card{
  display:block;
  background-color:green;
  border:2px solid black;
  overflow-x:auto;
  whitespace:nowrap;
}  
.card-body{
  display:block;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
         <div class="card h-100 py-2">
            <div class="card-body">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```